# Adding Animation to Widgets during Scroll in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am working on a Flutter project and would like to add animations to widgets as I scroll through the screen. Specifically, I want each widget to load with a certain animation when it comes into view during scrolling.

I have tried a few approaches but haven't been successful so far. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this in Flutter?

Comment: something like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations ?

Comment: @IncorrectMouse Thank you for answering.
it's working but using this package animation can been load at initial time but i need to add while user can scroll screen data animation can be load at that time so how to do in flutter.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibility_detector: ^0.4.0+2` package and wrap with your widget
or control your animation timing using  onVisibilityChanged function.